# Has Bell really demonstrated that no local hidden variable theory can exist in his original paper of 1964? Why then verify the CHSH violation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bells-inequality

The more I read about it and the more I'm convinced I haven't understood what I thought I had.

In the original paper `J. S. Bell, On the Einstein Podolsky Rosen paradox, Physics 1, 195, 1964.` ([link](http://philoscience.unibe.ch/documents/TexteHS10/bell1964epr.pdf)), there is a section (the section **IV**) where

- The Bell inequality $1 + P(\vec{b},\vec{c}) \geq \left |P(\vec{a},\vec{b}) - P(\vec{a},\vec{c}) \right |$ takes form
- The fact that $\epsilon$ cannot be made arbitrarily small for all $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ in the expression $\left |\overline{P}(\vec{a},\vec{b}) + \vec{a}.\vec{b} \right |\leq \epsilon$, which implies that no local hidden variable theory can exist to arbitrarily closely approach the quantum mechanical predictions.

My question is this :

If my interpretation of the second bullet point is right, what's the point of verifying the CHSH inequality by experiments since it has been proved by Bell in this article that it's impossible ? Does the fact that we have $\overline{P}$ and not simply $P$ change anything ?

Comment: In the second point, Bell didn't show that a local hidden variable theory was logically inconsistent, just that it would produce predictions different from those produced by quantum mechanics ("no local hidden variable theory can...approach the QM predictions"). The experiments then tested those predictions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The general point of experiments is checking how nature actually behaves.

Bell demonstrated that local hidden variable assumptions do in fact produce restrictions on the possible predictions of theories based on such assumptions, and that these restrictions leave some of the results of quantum mechanics out of the reach of LHV theories. This draws an observable line between them, and it is therefore desirable to check by experiment which way nature actually is: are the predictions of quantum mechanics always observed, even when they would be predicted by "common sense" LHV assumptions? If that is not the case, then such experiments should unearth a breaking of quantum mechanics which would also be very interesting in their own right.